# How to set custom access for a custom page?

Tags: 8, users

For example, there is a page on the site, created before.

I need to set custom permission for it.

Par example, if a user doesn't have a photo in his profile, he shouldn't have access to page "/forum".

On Drupal 7 it was possible via hook_menu_alter and set access control there.

Could you clarify me, how can I it on Drupal 8 ?

Comment: see the documentation https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes

Comment: I asked how to change access on existing route, not on route, creating by myself. That is, how to bind my custom access function to an existing route.

Comment: This is the next page in the doc https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

Comment: Thank you, I've read it, but encounted with a problem.
Namely, there is a class method
`$route->setRequirement('some_key', 'some_regex');`
My services.yml file is 
`services:
  yrv_page_access.forum_route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\yrv_page_access\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
  yrv_page_access.forum_access:
    class: Drupal\yrv_page_access\Access\CustomAccessCheck
    arguments: ['@current_user']
    tags:
      - { name: forum_access_check, applies_to: _forum_access_check }
`
How I should write setRequirement to assign my access ?

Comment: `$route->setRequirement('_forum_access_check', 'TRUE');`

Comment: I did it, but access function doesn't execute.
Here's my RouteSubscriber class
https://slexy.org/view/s2hkaNp8rv
Here's my Access class
https://slexy.org/view/s21U2jXH30
And here's my services.yml file
https://slexy.org/view/s20aLMJTK1

I want to forbid access to the /forum page for all users.
But access is allowed.
What wrong am I doing ?

Comment: You need to use   `$route->setRequirement('_custom_access', '\Drupal\yrv_page_access\Access\ForumAccessCheck::access');` and return `AccessResult` in `ForumAccessCheck`. See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example which prevents anonymous users from resetting their password.

services.yml:

```
services:
  mymodule.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\MymoduleRouteSubscriber
    tags: 
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

src/Routing/MymoduleRouteSubscriber.php:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class MymoduleRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {

    if ($route = $collection->get('user.pass')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_custom_access', '\Drupal\mymodule\Access\ResetPasswordAccessCheck::access');      
    }
  }

}
```

src/Access/ResetPasswordAccessCheck.php:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

class ResetPasswordAccessCheck {

  /**
   * A custom access check.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   Run access checks for this account.
   */
  public function access(AccountInterface $account) {

    return $account->isAnonymous() ? AccessResult::forbidden() : AccessResult::allowed();

  }

}
```

I've updated the documentation to clarify what return value is expected: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes

**Forum access example**

You only need the route subscriber in services.yml:

```
services:
  yrv_page_access.forum_route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\yrv_page_access\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

RouteSubscriber:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\yrv_page_access\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection){
    if ($route = $collection->get('forum.index')){
      $route->setRequirement('_custom_access', '\Drupal\yrv_page_access\Access\ForumAccessCheck::access');
    }
  }
}
```

Access check:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\yrv_page_access\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/*
 * Custom access to the forum page
 */
class ForumAccessCheck {

  public function access(AccountInterface $account){
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I run a custom access check for *all* routes in Drupal?  Just iterate the $collection in alterRoutes() or is there a simpler way?

Comment: You could get all routes or use the iterator (see documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21routing%21RouteCollection.php/class/RouteCollection/8.7.x ) but it's probably easiest to use the addRequirements() method:  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21routing%21RouteCollection.php/function/RouteCollection%3A%3AaddRequirements/8.7.x

Comment: BTW, internally `addRequirements()` just iterates over all routes, so there's no technical benefit.

Comment: The technical benefit is cleaner and more concise code. Why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: All access checks must implement AccessInterface.

Comment: @JuyalJee It's not necessary any more.  Ref: https://www.drupal.org/node/2731311 While the related issue is set to "needs work", I'm not sure why. Access checks work fine without implementing the interface, as per the example in my answer.

Comment: Just to confirm, the change record is still a "Draft".